# I have some trouble with PHP sha256 Hash

Tags: php

I want to hash the user input and save it in a database but i only safe the same hash every time no matter what password i enter in. Why is this so ? i know that the function return the hash as hezadezimal but it should be diffrent with other passwords?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="index3.php" method="post">
    email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
    passwort: <input type="text" name="passwort"/>
    name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Registrieren" name="submit"/>
</form>


<?php
    $file = "./logingfile.txt";
    $filename = "./logingfile.txt";
    $result = false;
    $servername = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pw = "";
    $db = "user"; 

    $con = new mysqli($servername, $user, $pw, $db);

    if($con->connect_error){
        die("ende".$con->connect_error);    
    }
    $hashed = hash('sha256', $_POST["password"]); // i think here is the problem
    $sql = "INSERT INTO login (id, name, email, passwort) 
    VALUES (NULL,'".$_POST["name"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$hashed."' )"; 

    $result = $con->query($sql);

    if($result == false){
        echo $con->error;
    }
    echo $_POST["passwort"];
    echo $hashed;


    file_put_contents($filename, $sql, FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents($filename, "\n", FILE_APPEND);



?>

</body>
</html>
```

P.S: i know this isnt the securest code, its only for test purposes where i can understand a little bit about sql injections

Comment: Stop. Abort mission. Use the secure password hashing PHP already has built into it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of this line:

```
$hashed = hash('sha256', $_POST["password"]);
```

It should be `$_POST["passwort"]`, just a mispelling